# Trying to get JSONP but JS thinks that I'm pointing to other JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

I'm trying to download JSONP from other server but I still getting error (in FF inspector `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`).
To connect with server I'm using simple $.getJSON:

```
$.getJSON(url + "?callback=?", function(data) {
            $("#main").html(data);       
});
```

On the server I have this JSON:

```
{"branchName":"war140820rc1","commitId":"fcf600371bc9e837290799e0d7f7e848ccf12e7d"}
```

What is my problem? I checked this code multiple times and it looks like other JSONP downloaders.

Comment: Your server is sending JSON, not JSONP. JSONP looks like `callbackname({"branchName":"war140820rc1",...});`

Comment: So how could I download this JSON from other server? I with normal ajax I have problem with Same Origin Policy

Comment: There are many questions answering how to get around the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the request will look something like this:

```
<script src="http://yourdomain.com/?callback=callback"></script>
```

Which means it is handled as a Javascript file. Therefor you the callback passed in `?callback=` should be called like every other javascript function, and you pass the result in json. Like:

```
callback(<?= MYJSON ?>);
```

Comment: So how can I download this JSON without breaking Same Origin Policy?

Comment: The JSONP doesnt break the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: but I cannot change what is on server. I need to download JSON without breaking SOP.

Comment: Then use a normal JSON call to your own server. And download the JSON with a PHP function `file_get_contents`.